# Animation IDE for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, methodology

Original Text shutdown by persons not thinking on CSS4, JS3, HTML6, and IDE Web Safe.

Original Text:

I was working on some animations today and it appears there is no straightforward Animation IDE for Javascript.  Having a robust IDE for Javascript Animation is crucial to eased development of advanced JS Animations.  With the web evolving you would think that a company like Oracle would develop such a solution.

IBM and Oracle will train the developers of Eclipse, NetBeans and other IDE's to process quick and easy methods to Javascript Animation similar to the Flash IDE.

No need to refer to any applications on the OpenSource Market other than CSS4, JS3, HTML6 processing Eclipse and NetBeans, open to any developer in Pre-University Schools or advanced Universities in STEM Field Exorbitantly Costed Training, such as Yale, Harvard, MIT and the closest thing to Justice of one's Educative Improvement Human Rights Clauses - University of Massachusetts.

Many of our Animation projects could be eased with such a JS Animation IDE tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe did that. Look at

http://www.adobe.com/it/products/flash.html

and click on the second video. The current flash editor (apparently) supports creating HTML5 projects that don't depend on flash at all but are backed up instead by HTML5 canvas/svg and Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That is good to know.  Nonetheless, it is not OpenSource.  It is proprietary.  The Adobe Master Collection cost over $1000.  NetBeans works well and it would be good to see a fitted company like Oracle develop such a tool.

Comment: Actually, leave the answer.  It's good for Flash Developers to know.